# How to create a custom route to handle the redirection of routes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router` where I have following code

```
       <Router basename={config.historyBasename}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path={routes.landingPage} element={<LandingPage />} />
            <Route
              path={routes.activateAccount}
              element={
                !document.referrer.length ? (
                  redirectTo(appUrls.home)
                ) : (
                  <Parent/>
                )
              }
            />
           
          </Routes>
        </Router>
```

Here, I am using `redirectTo` which I created custom method. Now here, I am trying to create a custom route which will do

```
              <Route
              path={routes.activateAccount}
              element={
                !document.referrer.length ? (
                  redirectTo(appUrls.home)
                ) : (
                  <Parent/>
                )
              }
            />
```

this. How can I create a custom route which will handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

The past couple of years, `react-router-dom` and `react-router` introduced the `<Redirect />` component which essentially when rendered, redirects the user to a specified location.

For example:

```
<Route exact path="/">
    <Redirect to={"/home"} />
</Route>
```

redirect the user to `/home` whenever he arrives on `/`.

When using `react-router-dom@^6.0.0`, refrain from using `Redirect` and use `Navigate` instead:

```
<Route 
    path="/"
    element={<Navigate to={"/home"} replace />}
/>
```

Which essentially serves the same purpose as the code I wrote above.

Comment: How do we adda custom route for this ?

Comment: Where do you keep the custom route? Is it a variable? If so, just replace "home" with the variable name as the to argument accepts any string regardless of if its literal or variable declaration. You can also do ternary operation inside of the to={} for example `to={true ? "/home" : some_string}` Same goes for `path` property - it also accepts any string. I should mention, only URL safe strings are accepted in `path` and `to`.

Comment: OP is using `react-router-dom@6` and the `Redirect` component is `react-router-dom@5` export, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I added v6 code, should work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use Redirect from react-router-dom for Conditionally Redirect to the Default Path

```
<Route
    path={routes.activateAccount}
    element={!document.referrer.length ? <Redirect to='/home' /> : <Redirect to='/second-route' />}
/>
```

For v6 you can use Navigate

```
<Route
    path={routes.activateAccount}
    element={
        !document.referrer.length ? (
        <Navigate replace to='/home' />
        ) : (
           <Navigate replace to='/second-route' />
        )
        }
    />
```

Please note however that this won't work when server rendering because the navigation happens in a React.useEffect().

Have a look at [Redirects in React Router v6](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/b5748add2795ce7448a366ae8f8ae3bb) for some deeper details.

Comment: Agreed , but is there any way we can create a custom route and handle this over there ? also Redirect is not available in V6

Comment: You can use Navigate in v6 let me update my answer